# How to return asset from custom user field

Tags: assets, craft3, assets-field

In Craft 3, one of my 'User' fields is an assets type field with one selectable asset ('profilePicture').

I have routing setup to load my template when a url looks like:

```
domain.com/person/firstname-lastname
```

In my template I am getting the appropriate user with:

```
{% set secondSegment = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}

{% set people = craft.users.group('family') %}

{% for person in people %}
    {% set personName = person.firstName|lower ~ "-" ~ person.lastName|lower %}
    {% if secondSegment == personName %}
        {% set currentUser = person %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All that works - I can query most fields, but I can't work out how to get my asset.

Works:

```
{{ currentUser.myTextField }}
```

None of these work (returns nothing and no error):

1.

```
{{ currentUser.profilePicture[0].url }}
```

2.

```
{% set asset = currentUser.profilePicture.first() %}

{% if asset %}
    {{ asset.getUrl }}
{% endif %}
```

3.

```
{% for asset in currentUser.profilePicture %}
    {{ asset.getUrl }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you enable URLs for this asset sources? If not the `getUrl` function will return null

Comment: @RobinSchambach Arg! <Smacks head> Thanks! If you want to write it up I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you enabled the option `Assets in this volume have public urls` in your volume settings at `/admin/settings/assets/volumes/`.

This checkbox is disabled by default thus your `getUrl()` function will always return an empty string/null.